# Button below ScrollView comes on top

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext, android-scrollview

I am having a hard time debugging a very simple problem. I have a layout of an activity where there is an `EditText` and a button below the `EditText` to do an operation. The problem is, I was typing long sentences into the `EditText`, it used to grow in height and the button was pushed beneath the screen. Here is my layout file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#231f20">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="#FAC80A"
        android:elevation="4dp">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView176"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
                android:src="@drawable/cta_ic_notifications_grey" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView109"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:text="Help"
                android:textColor="#231f20"
                android:textSize="20sp" />
        </RelativeLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView22"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
        android:alpha="0.8"
        android:text="We are here to help! We have recently launched the app and it is in beta. Not all features may be working in an optimal manner.In the meantime, if you have any feedback, or if there is any help you need, please reach out to us:"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="17sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView50"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="70dp"
        android:src="@drawable/help_contact_button_send_in_active" />

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:layout_above="@+id/imageView50"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView22">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText10"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:hint="How can we help you today?"
                android:inputType="textCapSentences|textMultiLine"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textColorHint="#707070"
                android:theme="@style/EditTextStyle" />

    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

What I want is, the send button should always be visible at bottom and no matter how long sentences I type into the `EditText`, it should scroll and be constrained between the header `TextView` and `ImageView` button. In this particular layout, as soon as I start typing, the send button comes on top and I am not able to see anything I type, it is only after closing the keyboard, that I am able to see the text and send button below it.

Comment: Align your button to parent bottom and your edittext above it

Comment: I had done that. It was not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside scrollview you are using Edittext and scrollview has height wrap_content, that is why it is happening. to solve this problem you can remove the scrollview and define the editText like this

```
<EditText
            android:id="@+id/add_task_notes"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-bold"
            android:hint="Notes"
            android:inputType="textCapSentences|textMultiLine"
            android:maxLines="5"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:textColor="@color/edit_text_color"
            android:textSize="@dimen/edit_text_font_size"></EditText>
```

this Edittext will give the scrollable text and maximum visible lines

If you want to make the whole layout scrollable then make ScrollView as your parent layout

Comment: `android:maxlines` was useful.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a vertical LinearLayout

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" ></LinearLayout>
```

in ScrollView

Your code is as below .............

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="320dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10" >

            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button" />

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```